# Splitting string input into discrete numbers and operators

Tags: java, string

I am trying to split a string like `"-10 5 + 3 *"` into component parts to use in basic arithmetic, while maintaining the integrity of operators, e.g. not confusing `-10` for the `-` operator and a `10`. How should I approach this?

Currently I am doing a simple split based on a space delimiter, and intend to write individual methods to deal with each operation. However this does not account for inputs with no spaces: example `"11+1+1"`. I have explored delimiting by every character e.g. `string.split("")` but missing something in the logic.

```
String[] simplifyCommand(String s) {
    return s.split(" ");
    //or s.split(""); for individual characters
  }
```

Comment: How would your first test string `"-10 5 + 3 *"` be split? -10 and 5 are not joined by any operator

Comment: An idea. What if you iterated through the string. When string[i] is not a number (0-9), capture everything before that into an item (only going as far back as the symbol). Once broken into an array of [`11`, `+1`,`+1`], you can do more string processing to finish the equation.

Comment: @Robo Mop I am going to use reverse polish notation, so -10 and 5 will be added to the stack as ints, then the + operator applied, the -10 and 5 will be popped off and the result pushed in place of.

Comment: @Cooper Scott that is a good idea thank you, how would you guard against taking the whole of the beginning of the string with that segment, feels like recursion could be used?

Comment: Okay, but that still doesn't answer the question: how is `-10 5` a valid expression? What does it even mean?

Comment: Regex? `Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]+|[*\\/+-]")`?

Comment: @RoboMop as I explained that is not an expression, in RPN the operands are added to a data structure and then the data structure is operated on

Comment: @Darkman thank you I will need to look this up as not familiar with Regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\b` word boundary regex anchor to split your input string into digits and operators:

```
"11+1+1".split("\\b");
```

Above expression would produce `[11, +, 1, +, 1]` as its result so you can iterate through the result as is.

Likewise, `"11+1+1".split("\\b")` would produce `[-, 11, +, 1, +, 1]` as a result. This should not make it any harder to interpret the operation itself.

Comment: It won't allow for negative integers though?

Comment: Indeed, the regular expression won't account for neither *negative* numbers nor spaces.